# Geometrised Units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, physical-constants, unit-conversion, absolute-units

I am curious as to how to express a area units in [geometrised ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system). I was reading on wikipedia and saw that when angular momentum is converted into geometrised units, it is expressed as a dimension of area by multiplying by a factor of $Gc^{-3}$ so for area would the geometrised units be in angular momentum dimension? Maybe take for an example an area of $3m^2$.

Comment: In the table at the bottom of the wiki page you cite, the first entry is lenght, in geometrised units, it stays the same with a multiplication factor of 1. So an area stays an area in $m^2$

Comment: is there a reason why it stays the same or is it just because length is the same so area is the same?

Comment: The reason is that in geometrized units we usually keep the unit of length as the fundamental one: the meter doesn't change, and so the squared meter doesn't change either.